# Tilde over n when when converting from markdown to latex with pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown document that I convert to PDF via pandoc's latex engine. I'm trying to render an n with a tilde over it, as in "niño", with markdown like the following:

```
ni\~{n}o
```

...but this just gets rendered in the PDF as "ni~no" -- i.e. the tilde gets interpreted literally. I've also tried escaping the backslash (`ni\\~{n}o`), surrounding everything in brackets (`ni{\~{n}}o`), and basically what I think is every possible combination of escaping characters in this sequence, but nothing works. It also fails even when the sequence is on its own (i.e. `\~{n}`).

But, other similar sequences that are based on letters rather than symbols  work just fine (e.g. `Otter\r{a}` gets rendered correctly to "Otterå"). Pandoc is specifically failing to handle the tilde (or maybe more generally non-letter-based latex character sequences -- I haven't tested others).

The command I'm using to build the pdf is `pandoc file.md -o file.pdf`. I've also tried specifying `-f markdown+raw_tex`, but it still fails (nor should I need to, since the `\r{a}` works without it, and I think `raw_tex` is enabled by default anyway).

Any thoughts? I know I can use xetex to just enter these characters directly, but that's not really a satisfying solution...

Comment: Have you tried using `ñ` directly?

Comment: No, but that's not really the point of the question -- as I mentioned, to use Unicode characters in markdown, I'm pretty sure I would have to compile using the `xelatex` engine instead of native latex, not to mention having a terminal and text editor that support those characters. Which I do, but I'd like to have a more robust and platform-agnostic workflow.

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that pandoc automatically deals with Unicode characters. I assumed it would break on them, but I guess it switches to xelatex if it detects any in the document, which is pretty nifty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides using the `ñ` character directly (which apparently works in native Pandoc because it's magic!), an alternative is to create a simple LaTeX `\newcommand` for forcing native TeX interpretation.

```
\newcommand{\tex}[1]{#1}

ni\tex{\~n}o
```

Thanks to [John McFarlane](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2880#issuecomment-215304484) for introducing me to this clever workaround!